# Display blob present in session in JSP

Tags: jsp, blob

I get a blob type object from a database from a class call StatusDAO:

```
    public static List<Status> getStatus(String user, List<User> friends){
        List<Status> status = new ArrayList<Status>();
        Status s;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Status where owner = ?");
            ps.setString(1, user);  
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                s = new Status();
                s.setIdStatus(rs.getInt("idStatus"));
                s.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                s.setText(rs.getString("text"));    
                s.setByteArray(byteArray);
                s.setImage(rs.getBlob("image"));
                s.setPublicationDate(rs.getDate("date"));
                s.setOwner(rs.getString("owner"));
                status.add(s);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getGlobal().info(e.getMessage());
        }

        return status;
    }
```

I go through a servlet to send the retrieved information

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
        //Récupération du user en session
        String userSession = getUserSession(request);
        request.setAttribute("userSession", userSession);

        //Récupération des status
        List<Status> s = new ArrayList<Status>();
        s = StatusDAO.getStatus(userSession, l);
        request.setAttribute("listStatus", s);

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/UserJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

And in my JSP i've this :

```
    <c:forEach items="${ listStatus }" var="s">
        <h3><c:out value="${ s.owner }" /></h3>
        <h4><c:out value="${ s.title } - ${ s.publicationDate }" /></h4>
        <p><c:out value="${ s.text }" /></p>
        <img src="${ s.image }" width="400px"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

And as a result everything works except the image.
I get an icon.

[image: What i get]

So how do I display the image?
Thanks

Comment: What do you see as the source of the image if you right-click on it and click on Inspect?

Comment: @LajosArpad I get this : <img src="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Blob@40b5d28f" width="400px">

Comment: Will ```<img src="${ new String(s.image.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length())) }" width="400px"/>``` work?

Comment: @LajosArpad An error appears: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${ new String(s.image.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length())) }]